# conditional subtraction between 4 fields

Tags: calculated-column

I need to create a calculation that basically is a subtraction between two fields (2 date fields). However it should be done only if a 3rd field is equal to a value of 5 or 6 AND a fourth field  less than 500.

- My first field is director approval date
- My second field is finance approval date
- My third field is either 5,6,7 or 8
- My fourth filed is cost per person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula will be something like this:

```
=IF(AND([Column 4]<500,OR([Column 3]=5,[Column 3]=6)),[Date 2]-[Date 1],"-")
```

Comment: How can you check if column 4 is less than 500 with a string type (the quotes) ? This is not working...

Comment: Hi Jay, if column is single line of text then quotes are required, if column is of type number then quotes are not required

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't make sense the check if a single line of text is less than 500.

Comment: Hi Jay, if column is single line of text and you put numeric value in that you will need to use quotes for comparison. You can try this. I have tested it and it works. And why I assumed that Luis is using single line of text, because Luis asked the similar question in another thread in this forum. My assumption might be wrong. If column type is Number then i agree that quotes are not required.

Comment: If Column4 is Single Line of Text and has 4000 for value, evaluating this results a TRUE value : =Column4<"500". A string comparison (alphabetical order) is different than a numerical comparison. It is logically false, but a fully functionnal formula.

Comment: Yes. Got your point. I have edited the answer. @Luis: Please check at your end also

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND([Column4]<500, OR([Column3]=5,[Column3]=6,[Column3]=7,[Column3]=8)),DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d"),"")
```

This will return the number of days between the two dates.

Help with calculated columns : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for clarification. I Got your Point. I try to delete the answer, but it not allowed me as it was already accepted. So I edited that. Thanks once again